# Calculate or estimate 3-phase 400V heat pump (inductive) load

Tags: three-phase, inductive, heater

My water heating system (CTC) consist of a air-to-water heat pump and a water tank with an immersion heater. It is all powered from the same electronics pack and hooked up to 400V (3-phase) with a 25A fuse. Since it is connected to my smart home system with modbus I can read a lot of the data it provides. I want to figure out the total power usage so I can optimize when I run heat pump and when I use the immersion heater.

The immersion heater power usage can be read directly from the data and is typically around 5-6 kW on max. Getting to know how much the heat pump draws is much harder though (someone said that the reason is that the immersion heater is a resistive load, but the pump is inductive?).

I have access to a lot of real-time data, which I thought should be enough to at least estimate the load of the heat pump, e.g.:

- current per phase on the heating system totally (heat pump + immersion heater) [A]
- immersion heater load [kW]
- voltage per phase in my house [V]
- power factor (total for my house) [%] (usually between 60-100%)
- total load for my house [kW]
- heat pump status (on/off)

I can check the heat pump load in retrospect by examining the total load for my house in retrospect. An example of this is from a couple of weeks ago:

- Total load on the house before heat pump started (and after it stopped): ~500 W
- Heat pump ran for ca 20 minutes: Total load increased with ~1.95 kW in the period
- Current: ~3.8 A for each of the three phases in the 20min period
- Voltage: ~235V for each of the three phases

Another example from where both immersion heater and heat pump is in use:

- Total load on house when heat pump and immersion heater off: 950 W
- Total load on house when heat pump on: 2460 W
- Current when only heat pump runs: ~3.9 A on each of the three phases
- Voltage when only heat pump runs: 237-238 V on each phase
- When immersion heater starts (Heat pump also active): Current increases to ~15A on each phase, immersion heater load is ~5.5 kW.

Can anyone provide me with a solution I can implement from all this data to calculate or estimate the real-time heat pump load?

Comment: Add a meter for just your heat-pump else it's guesswork.